# View will not show up on table view cell on Xcode 7/iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I am updating my to-do application to iOS 9. I have been wrestling with this issue since Xcode 7b1 and not sure if this is a bug or not. In my app, I have a checkbox to the right of the cell: [image]

The checkbox does not show up in the preview or on device for some reason (ignore the off bar button items in the preview/storyboard, that is clearly a bug):
 [image][image]

Here are my constraints, sizes, and positions: 
[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution to your problem:

1) Set the leading constraint priority to 999

2) Get rid of the top constraint (it's redundant as you have the 'Align Center Y' constraint)

3) Set height and width constraints.

Hope this helps!